# Horizontal scroll appears on website when using iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I have a problem with mobile version of my website http://dsmedvednikov2.zzz.com.ua/. A horizontal scroll appears when using iPhone or iPad, no matter whether using Safari or Google Chrome browser. Everything works fine on Android devices. Could someone give me an advice?

Comment: You are using fixed widths which may be larger than the screen width. Can you post the dimensions of the devices which work and the ones which don't?

Comment: Please provide us with the code to the website. But so far, what I can tell you is that an element is expanding the width of the webpage, thus going beyond the viewport width. To see what element is doing this, give all elements a border, from where you can see what element is taking up that space.

Comment: Everything works fine in chrome's developer emulator on my desktop and all Android devices, so I don't think that problem is about some element's width, maybe it is some kind of iOS problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict user to stop zoom/pinch on your website by adding this meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

or if its a very minute x-scroll effect you can use the following little hack:

```
body    {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

it will stop any horizontal scroll effect.

Comment: This is an incorrect way to go about this type of problem. It would be best to first determine what element is causing the webpage to expand beyond the viewport width, then modify it so it behaves normally on mobile devices. You are providing a quick workaround, and those pose greater problems down the road.

Comment: but he said that the website works fine in android devices so maybe there isnt the problem with some element's  width .That why i suggested the meta tag solution.Every website put the meta tag (width=device-width) better responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution didn't work anyway

Comment: There are many other factors that might make an element render incorrectly on one browser and not another. An example might be using vendor-specific CSS prefixes incorrectly, causing unintended behaviour. The first step is to determine **what** is causing the issue, before trying to resort to an arbitrary solution.

Comment: just for a last check did you put *{box-sizing:border-box;}? Sometimes while developing devs forgot to put this minor property in the beginning causing error afterwards

Comment: This didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the page css is making this mess. Even in safari on my Mac getting the same issue. Please make sure your CSS.

As of my knowledge I gone through the CSS properties of your page [image: CSS of body tag]

which is causing the issue. It will be better if you use % instead of 'px' will resolve your issue.

Thanks! 
Keep Coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fixed width, then it might lead to problems. Use **

> width:100%

**

Answer (score 0):

iOS browsers will auto-zoom the input elements if the size is less than 16 pixels.

```
@media (max-width:500px) {

    input[type="color"],
    input[type="date"],
    input[type="datetime"],
    input[type="datetime-local"],
    input[type="email"],
    input[type="month"],
    input[type="number"],
    input[type="password"],
    input[type="search"],
    input[type="tel"],
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="time"],
    input[type="url"],
    input[type="week"],
    select:focus,
    textarea {
        font-size: 16px !important;
    }
}
```